# What does my wife want?

Tags: word, wordplay, pattern, connect-wall

I asked my wife what she wants to do this weekend and she sent me this confusing message.
What does this all mean?

```
Pal, under, load, grade.
Trade, down, bench, question.
Bow, acid, forest, fall.
Dutch, time, trouble, cross.
Nova, majority, position, visor.
Leg, service, ball, wash.
Cast, burn, wipe, lash.
Plan, rising, figure, legal.
Heart, even, tie, dance.
Air, drop, sand, bin.
Noise, snow, label, plague.
Animal, house, line, after.
Miracle, stone, green, post.
Price, year, wedge, generation.
Cold, key, fish, gem.
Focus, theory, work, interest.
```

The answer is a single word.

Comment: So the sixteen words are themselves four groups of four?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the solution, using @RobPratt's strong start and hints from @M Oehm

1 -> 2

> Making 4 2nd-layer words from 16 1st-layer words.

> pay, mark, rain, double -> check (thanks @M Oehm)

> super, room, out, action -> class

> break, box, white, party -> tea (thanks @M Oehm)

> mile, gap, stone, group -> age

2 -> 3

> Making 1 3rd-layer word from 4 2nd-layer words

> check, class, tea, age -> mate (final answer, which turns out to be a weekend activity for couples)

Comment: line 7 is "outcast" (1). Last line is "workgroup" (0).

Comment: @fectin but "cast out" and "group work" are both viable options

Comment: And, for that matter, so is "Coldstone"

Comment: For what it's worth, I've got rot13(purpx) for #1. I couldn't find a good word for #3 rot13(va? grn?), but the remaining words give me [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mate) popular weekend activity (varb, sense 2) for couples. (But really, such a long-winded puzzle for that?)

Comment: @MOehm rot13(V guvax lbhe "purpx" svgf gur svefg 4 orggre guna zl "qbja" fvapr vg svgf "enva" orggre. Naq lbhe "grn" svgf gur guveq 4 orggre. Ohg abgr gung "grnzzngr" vf fcryyrq jvgu gjb z'f, jurernf "vazngr" jbexf ohg "va" qbrfa'g dhvgr svg gur guveq 4. )

Comment: I'm not really happy with "tea", but for the final connection, I thought about [this tea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mate_(drink)), which might be iffy, but so is the "age" in "mileage".

Comment: @MOehm yea I think that tea is the key. For mileage, it's perfectly fine because of similar things like supernova

Comment: Nice, though instead of rot13(obk) I was thinking rot13(ont). Good enough for the tick imo nonetheless.

Comment: I agree rot13(zngr grn) is not the best answer, but my problem not yours:)

Answer (score 7):

Pal, under, load, grade.

> pay

Trade, down, bench, question.

> mark

Bow, acid, forest, fall.

> rain

Dutch, time, trouble, cross.

> double

Nova, majority, position, visor.

> super

Leg, service, ball, wash.

> room

Cast, burn, wipe, lash.

> out

Plan, rising, figure, legal.

> action

Heart, even, tie, dance.

> break

Air, drop, sand, bin.

> box

Noise, snow, label, plague.

> white

Animal, house, line, after.

> party

Miracle, stone, green, post.

> mile

Price, year, wedge, generation.

> gap

Cold, key, fish, gem.

> stone

Focus, theory, work, interest.

> group

The single word is:

> movies

Upon further review, it appears that the 16 words are instead all related to the single activity:

> Nintendo

Comment: How did you get the final single word?

Comment: @Amoz By noticing that combining the missing word with each of the others in the same group yields a rot13(zbivr gvgyr).

Comment: @RobPratt I agree with all your missing-word solutions, and indeed many of them are compatible with your final single-word answer, but many are not compatible (at least from my cursory search): *majority, rising, heart, air, bin, price, wedge, theory, interest*. I think your single-word answer is sufficiently general, and the candidates are sufficiently short, so it is easy to convince yourself that it fits, when some of them don't actually fit. Please let me know if I missed something in my search though.

Comment: I agree that the suggested overall answer is very loose and observe that there are exactly rot13(fvkgrra) groups of four words ...

Comment: @MOehm Are you suggesting a refinement of my overall answer that instead uses that number?

Comment: And could my last name be another clue?

Comment: Related to @MOehm's idea, I constructed some potentially relevant data. You may see my answer for it (not a full solution of course).

Comment: In a way, yes, but conceptually rather than literally: I suggest that you continue your good work a bit further until the final answer emerges. Perhaps you'll like that answer better than "movies"... `;)`

Comment: @RobPratt, you are close. Apologies upon inspection, I realized I made a small typo on one of the words, perhaps in this direction, you would be able to solve the puzzle?

Comment: @RobPratt, you got the first step of the puzzle (mostly) right. Your final answer is wrong though.