# What does my wife want (again)?

Tags: word, connections-puzzle

After an enjoyable, if not very tiring, [weekend](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122139/what-does-my-wife-want), I was working when I suddenly remembered that it is my wife's birthday this coming Saturday! Frantically, I texted her, asking what she wants for that special occasion, and she replied with a confusing message (again!).

What does this all mean?

> Ra**t**e, huck, hail, mire (=> post).
> Ripe, p**u**le, west, name.
> Deem, haen, c**o**ne, oral.
> Br**a**t, yale, rise, beak.
> Dart, fest, fla**y**, pose.
> Scar, soil, **c**ost, drew.
> Each, til**e**, topi, code.
> Rove, tide, dire, bi**n**d.
> Aide, rich, ide**a**, bass.
> Mi**t**y, able, mime, vino.
> Froe, bias, farl, bis**h**.
> Flow, fill, race, ha**i**r.
> Piny, lede, **n**oni, lure.
> Aced, lice, mise, qui**t**.
> Sade, tr**o**t, vein, slip.
> Clip, jeon, **s**and, mars.

The answer is a single word.

Comment: Just a wild guess: she wants rot13(qvibepr). That's the most logical explanation for sending you all that gibberish !

Comment: @Evargalo ah yes, the perfect gift any wife wants for her birthday

Comment: Could you give a hint